# Scalable automatic email classification service

Tags: java, ruby, email, scalability

We're currently working on an application that enable the user to register with one or more email account so that his emails could be automatically classified. The front-end has been implement using Ruby, however, the back-end (email classifier) is written in java and uses the WEKA API. The question is how could we integrate the front-end (Web interface written in Ruby) with the back-end (email classifier written in java) in a scalable way (handling large number of users simultaneously..

Comment: It's hard for me to see what kind of advice you're looking for from us; this problem statement is pretty small, and it's not obvious what options you've tried, how they didn't work as required, and what options might be available...

Comment: Thanks sarnoid. We're currently investigating the available options, we were considering using something like IronMQ [link(http://www.iron.io/products/mq) to communicate between the front-end and the back-end. The advice I'm looking for is: what's the best way to implement this application, should the code that monitors the user inbox folder be placed in the front-end or the back-end?? how could we develop the App in a way that supports multiple users in the same time without performance degradation..

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is an email classifier. But in any similar problem, the best solution I recommend creating a RESTful API for your java service. This can be done very elegantly with the right tools. The API should be over HTTP which returns JSON. Use a library like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) that serialize to JSON.

On the ruby side, you an easily parse that JSON and deserialize.

This is a very scalable solution because HTTP calls are stateless and already scalable. Thread is used and thrown away. If you need more power, then just add more machines.

The Rails app can also start caching some calls. But that is premature optimization.

If there is no logic and only a common database, then just share that common database between the two apps. But it sounds like the Java app needs to do some work. This is a common approach with APIs. It also doesn't limit you to Ruby. You can create JSONP service for AJAX or any other client that can understand JSON.

Comment: Thanks Amir. The email classifier simply categorizes an incoming emails into folders based on the training data provided by the user. To do this, the mail inbox for the user has to be continuously monitored to check for recent incoming emails, do you suggest adding this functionality to the ruby front-end? why? why not? thanks

Comment: I suggest you adding it to where it makes sense. Traditionally a service like this doesn't belong on the front-end. If you need to poll the user's inbox every x seconds then make it external for sure. If it is something only when a user clicks a button then create a separate library that is decoupled from the web application and use it as dependency in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new email alert just reverse which RESTful API you are exposing. Instead of exposing the Java app as a RESTful API, expose the Rails app API. For example `/user/ID/newmail`.

The Java app would then call the Rails app when a new email arrives.

Btw:

How did you implement a scalable system in Java for checking 1000s of email accounts?

Answer (score 0):

As the amount of data you're using to train the classifier with grows, you may find that you might want to use ensemble algorithms (where a group of n nodes form the ensemble) and split the training data up over each of the n nodes.

To classify a new datapoint, you can use a voting system where each of the n nodes gets to "vote" on what the new datapoint should be classified as.  The classification with the most votes wins.